# Angular 13 adding ngx-sharebuttons getting error like "Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/clipboard' or its corresponding type declarations."

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, angular13, ngx-share

i am making a web site in angular 13 with using Bootstrap 5 Laravel api etc .Here i use a share social media button for my pages. when i install ngx-sharebuttons"and install npm successfully updated. but importing ngx-sharebuttons module in app.module.ts and input the ng serve i got error like this "Module build failed" i will share my error in below image.please help.i am new in agular
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the guide on https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-sharebuttons/wiki/Share-Button-Directive you see:

`npm i ngx-sharebuttons @angular/cdk`

This command installs `@angular/cdk` alongside `ngx-sharebuttons`. `@angular/cdk` is a dependency of `ngx-sharebuttons`. So in your case, try:

`npm i @angular/cdk` and then serve your app again. The error should disappear.

**Edit**
We figured out more things to keep an eye on within the discussion:

- make sure you install `@angular/cdk` to the same version as your other angular dependencies
- make sure you use a compatible version of `ngx-sharebuttons` to your angular version. (v10 is for angular 13, v11 is for angular 14).

Comment: i thinks its on the basis of material ?is it right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: actually here above link using angular material. I m using bootstrp.so how to combine each other?

Comment: I dont read anything about material. Do you mean `@angular/cdk`?

Comment: yes i dont know about cdk

Comment: cdk is 'a set of behavior primitives for building UI components'. So it can be used by other component libraries like the one you want to use (ngx-sharebuttons). It does not stand directly in a connection to material.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248218/discussion-between-rishf-p-and-riscie).